# Android, Firebase, Realtime Database, onChildChanged called after onChildAdded?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Good evening.

I have a strange behavior with Firebase realtime database for Android.

I'll try to code a simple note app. My data structure is very simple:

- root

  - notes

    - uid

      - key

        - archived
        - color
        - date
        - text
        - **last_update**

Please, keep in mind **last_update** field.

I have the correct database reference in a service. In the onCreate I add a ValueEventListener to my reference. I choose this listener because I want that when the service is created, synck each note for that logged user.

Inside the `onValueChanged` method, after data handling, I remove the `ValueEventListener` and I add the `ChildEventListener`, for handle CRUD operations (adding, removing, updating).

Until now everything works great.

My code is:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(){

...

database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("notes" + "/" + "current_user_uid");

database.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);

}
```

So, my `ValueEventListener` is:

```
private ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.d(TAG, "main --> " + dataSnapshot.toString());

        ...//some stuff for saving data in a local sqlite db, nothing related to my problem


        database.removeEventListener(this);

        database.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
        //so here I have removed the ValueEventListener and I have attached a ChildEventListener.

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("firebase", databaseError.toString());
    }
};
```

Ok, my `ChildEventListener` is:

```
private ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Log.d(TAG, "add --> " + dataSnapshot.toString());

        ...//code for saving on my local db
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Log.d(TAG, "update --> " + dataSnapshot.toString());

        ...//code for updating on my local db
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.d(TAG, "delete --> " + dataSnapshot.toString());
        ...//code for deleting from my local db        }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Log.d(TAG, "moved --> " + dataSnapshot.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, "error --> " + databaseError.toString());
    }
};
```

Ok, until now, everything works.

Problems starts when I have tried to exclude notes already received. I use this code:

```
database.orderByChild(last_update).startAt(time).addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
```

obviously, the variable **time** is 0 for the first call, then I use SharedPreferences for save the value of `System.currentTimeMillis` inside each callback. I do the same for the `ChildEventListener`. Also, when a note is created/modified I use the value of `System.currenTimeMillis` for the field last_update.

So, if the logged user has no notes, everything works. But if there are some notes (for example, if I take a couple of notes and reboot the service), I don't receive the notes with last_update < time (correct), but when I try to update a note using:

```
childReference.child(uid).updateChildren(HashMap);
```

the `onNoteUpdated` callback is not called, is called `onNoteAdded`! Sometimes `onNoteUpdated` is called after `onNoteAdded`. But if I try to update several times a note, finally, after at least one call to `onNoteAdded`, `onNoteUpdated` works again.

I really don't understand why. Any suggestions?

Thanks.